# Should I delete this question with many upvotes?

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question

I asked this question years ago:

*[Is True = False in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947511/haskell-is-true-false)*

And now, it has 15 upvotes vs. 6 downvotes, plus it was marked as duplicate, plus it has two delete votes.

Should I delete it myself, or let the community decide? I like the question, but I'm confused because some people voted it good. Maybe it helps, maybe no... I don't know.

This case is pretty unique, since I asked a new question, *[Is True = False? Understanding binding and pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010100/is-true-false-understanding-binding-and-pattern-matching)*, and that question has good and helpful answers. The first one doesn't have answers and is very very similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Robert Columbia's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387271/2751851), which was written for an earlier version of this Meta question, provides good general advice about not deleting one's good duplicates. [Aaron Hall's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387429/2751851) covers why this concrete case ultimately had a resolution different than what Robert suggested. For the sake of closure, I will expand a bit on the sequence of events that led to the situation being discussed here.

The [target question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006500/what-does-let-5-10-do-is-it-not-an-assignment-operation) was asked in October 2015. [Its first, now deleted, duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010100/is-true-false-understanding-binding-and-pattern-matching) (the one Robert discusses in his answer) was asked in May 2017. It is a highly non-obvious duplicate. Having read the target back in 2015, I recognised it was ultimately the same issue, and hammered one question against the other. In April 2018, I chanced upon [the second duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48010100/2751851), which is nearly identical but, since it was a highly non-obvious duplicate just the same, had gotten two good answers. I also hammered the second duplicate.

A few days ago, that set of questions resurfaced through this Meta question. I suggested to Damian that the first duplicate should be deleted as redundant, and he agreed. Since then, the question was undeleted by other users, and then finally deleted again, which should suffice to settle the matter.

Comment: Finally the answer that solved all my doubts, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14):

[User *leftaroundabout* left a comment on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947511/is-true-false-in-haskell#comment82988935_43947511) which I agree with fully:

> you have asked the question to be reopened, however it remains a duplicate in the sense that the other question is about the fundamentally same paradox and has answers which elaborate why Haskell has this strange behaviour. Your question is still worthwhile (as reflected by the upvotes) as a redirect, because it's not obvious that True == False and 5 = 10 are quivalent in this regard, but they are.

Your question is a good example of a good signpost question (as it has been termed on Meta before). Someone else investigating this phenomenon might, as leftaroundabout mentioned, not think to look at the other question, suspecting that there was some sort of difference in boolean versus numeric behavior in this case. The "not obvious" is *key* here. *Obvious* duplicates are considered low-quality and worthy of near-immediate deletion. Your question is not obviously a dupe, but one that only emerges as a dupe with technical knowledge, which not every reader is going to have. That information, that this is the same phenomenon, is *helpful* information.

Your question should not be deleted due to its value, but it is right for it to be marked/closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

There are two duplicate questions:

[Is True = False? Understanding binding and pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48010100/is-true-false-understanding-binding-and-pattern-matching)

and the now deleted question you are specifically asking about:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947511/is-true-false-in-haskell

That now-deleted question is a near exact copy of the first duplicate question.

The first question is still a correctly tagged duplicate of:

[What does `let 5 = 10` do? Is it not an assignment operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33006500/what-does-let-5-10-do-is-it-not-an-assignment-operation)

Answers to that target question should also answer your duplicate question.

Keeping it the first dupe undeleted allows users to see it and its original responses, and redirects visitors to the original.

The near exact copy of the first dupe has no remaining purpose.

So I deleted the second dupe/exact copy. I know you now know this, but for other users, please do not make nearly exact copies of questions.

Comment: Very constructive answer, and helped me a lot to understand better the policy and code conduct of the site. Thanks so much